# How to efficiently tally co-occurrences in python list of lists

Tags: python, counter

I have a relatively large (~3GB, 3+ million entries) list of sublists where each sublist contains a group of tags. Here's a very simple example:

```
tag_corpus = [['cat', 'fish'], ['cat'], ['fish', 'dog', 'cat']]  

unique_tags = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'] 
co_occurences = {key:Counter() for key in unique_tags}

for tags in tag_corpus: 
    tallies = Counter(tags)
    for key in tags: 
        co_occurences[key] = co_occurences[key] + tallies
```

This works like charm, sort of, but it's SUPER slow on the actual data set, which has very large sublists (~30K total unique tags). Any python pros know how I can speed this thing up?

Comment: As a first approximation try bruteforce and replace the first forloop with [`joblib.Parallel`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html). Note that in this case you'll want a Counter per-list instead of a global one.

Comment: Also, you might want to try `line_profiler` to see which of the two blocks (`Counter` call or `co_occurences` update is more expensive).

Comment: Why are you sorting and what version of python?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: good point, sorting is not necessary. That's just an artifact of the previous approach I was taking. 2.7

Comment: @SergeiLebedev: interesting idea. am I correct that this would reduce the computation time by approx the number of CPUs used for the job?

Comment: @Aaron, I was going to suggest using regular dicts as per the newer answer if the order output was irrelevant, Counter dicts,  in particular using python 2 are not that fast unless you actually want some ordered output, there is a lot of overhead using Counters as your have a lot more going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* go faster. You'll have to measure.

```
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

tag_corpus = [['cat', 'fish'], ['cat'], ['fish', 'dog', 'cat']]

co_occurences = defaultdict(Counter)
for tags in tag_corpus:
    for key in tags:
        co_occurences[key].update(tags)
unique_tags = sorted(co_occurences)

print co_occurences
print unique_tags
```

Comment: WAY faster. Nice work, @Rob. This gets me what I need for now. Any insight into why this works as well as it does?

Answer (score 1):

I was just messing about not expecting to end up with anything more efficient, but with 100000 cats, dogs, and fishes, this is considerably faster, clocking in at 0.07 seconds as opposed to 1.25.

I was attempting to end up with a shorter solution, but it turned out this way was the fastest, even if it does look very simple :)

```
occurances = {}
for tags in tag_corpus:
    for key in tags:
        for key2 in tags:
            try:
                occurances[key][key2] += 1
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    occurances[key][key2] = 1
                except KeyError:
                    occurances[key] = {key2: 1}
```

Comment: thanks! fun solution, but the problem is that initializing that large dict of dicts with zero counts totally blows up the memory footprint. works well for small data i imagine.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you had lots of different tags, with the pets example I thought you had a 3m records of similar tags aha. Anyway, if you want to try it out again, I've hopefully fixed that problem. I tried it with `defaultdict` (just noticed that Padraic mentioned it), but it still slowed it down too much, a simple try/except seemed to work fine.

Comment: awesome, i'll be playing around with this more i expect. will let you guys know if i get further with another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try combing with a  *defaultdict* to avoid the initialization at the start using the logic from Peters answer, the runtime will be significantly faster:

```
In [35]: %%timeit
co_occurences = defaultdict(Counter)
for tags in tag_corpus:
    for key in tags:
        co_occurences[key].update(tags)
   ....: 

1 loop, best of 3: 513 ms per loop

In [36]: %%timeit
occurances = {k1: defaultdict(int) for k1 in unique_tags}
for tags in tag_corpus:
    for key in tags:
        for key2 in tags:
            occurances[key][key2] += 1
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 65.7 ms per loop

In [37]: %%timeit
   ....: co_occurences = {key:Counter() for key in unique_tags}
   ....: for tags in tag_corpus: 
   ....:     tallies = Counter(tags)
   ....:     for key in tags: 
   ....:         co_occurences[key] = co_occurences[key] + tallies
   ....: 
 1 loop, best of 3: 1.13 s per loop
    In [38]: %%timeit
   ....: occurances = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
   ....: for tags in tag_corpus:
   ....:     for key in tags:
   ....:         for key2 in tags:
   ....:             occurances[key][key2] += 1
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 66.5 ms per loop
```

At least in python2, a *Counter* dict is not actually the fastest way to get just the counts, a *defaultdict* however is fast even with the lambda.

Even rolling your own count function will be faster:

```
def count(x):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for ele in x:
        d[ele] += 1
    return d
```

Not quite as fast as the fastest but still pretty good:

```
In [42]: %%timeit
   ....: co_occurences = {key: defaultdict(int) for key in unique_tags}
   ....: for tags in tag_corpus:
   ....:     tallies = count(tags)
   ....:     for key in tags:
   ....:         for k, v in tallies.items():
   ....:             co_occurences[key][k] += v
   ....: 

10 loops, best of 3: 164 ms per loop
```

If you wanted more speedup, a bit of cython would probably go a long way.

Comment: awesome, i'll be playing around with this more i expect. will let you guys know if i get further with another solution. i haven't played around with cython yet, but doing stuff like this is making me think that this could be a good idea.